# Unicode receiving with ASP.NET core websocket

Tags: websocket, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm trying to build a websocket server using ASP.NET core 1.1 websocket middleware that can handle text messages. My strategy is to use a fixed-size buffer to keep reading and decoding until the websocket message ends. 
The middleware setup goes like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("websocket");

        app.UseWebSockets();

        app.Use(async (http, next) =>
        {
            if (!http.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                await next();
                return;
            }

            var websocket = await http.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();

            while (websocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[32]);
                var charbuffer = new char[32];
                try
                {
                    var sb = new StringBuilder();
                    var decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();

                    //aha, we got a message
                    var detectResult = await websocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
                    var receiveResult = detectResult;

                    while (!receiveResult.EndOfMessage)
                    {
                        var charLen = decoder.GetChars(buffer.Array, 0, receiveResult.Count, charbuffer, 0);
                        logger.LogInformation($"Decoded {charLen} byte(s) from wire");
                        sb.Append(charbuffer, 0, charLen);
                        receiveResult = await websocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
                    }
                    var charLenFinal = decoder.GetChars(buffer.Array, 0, receiveResult.Count, charbuffer, 0);
                    logger.LogInformation($"Decoded {charLenFinal} byte(s) from wire");
                    sb.Append(charbuffer, 0, charLenFinal);

                    var message = sb.ToString();
                    logger.LogInformation($"decoded message: {message}");
                    await websocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("got it")), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.LogError(ex.Message);
                    logger.LogError(ex.InnerException?.Message ?? string.Empty);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Now the code works well for text that include only ASCII characters. But when I tried to send Unicode text message (Vietnamese) whose length is longer than the buffer size, an exception occurs

```
fail: websocket[0]
  The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake.
fail: websocket[0]
     at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.<ReceiveAsyncPrivate>d__60.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
     at MvcApp.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<Configure>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

The exception occurs at the line

```
var detectResult = await websocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
```

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: Weird, those don't seem related, that error just says the client disconnected. Something wrong with your client?

Comment: @Tratcher I don't think so. It works perfectly for ASCII texts and Unicode with size smaller than the buffer size (32 in this case)

Answer (score 0):

I think this:

```
var charLenFinal = decoder.GetChars(buffer.Array, 0, receiveResult.Count, charbuffer, 0);
```

should be:

```
var charLenFinal = decoder.GetChars(buffer.Array, 0, receiveResult.Count, charbuffer, 0, true);
```

since:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/125z2etb(v=vs.110).aspx

> Remember that the Decoder object saves state between calls to
>   GetChars. When the application is done with a stream of data, it
>   should set the flush parameter to true to make sure that the state
>   information is flushed. With this setting, the decoder ignores invalid
>   bytes at the end of the data block and clears the internal buffer

.